# How to link a div in jsp page to a mysql table

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I am building a java web application and having a problem. My application is like this.

Users will login to application and in homepage they will be able to see queries from different users. A logged in user can comment on any query. I am managing different tables in mysql for each query. When a user comments on a query, the corresponding table should be updated with a new row which will contain the comment from the user.

Each user query in my web page is in different div tags. How would I associate those divs to the mysql tables?

How would I make sure in my code that when a user enters comment for a query and clicks submit then the corresponding table should be updated?

I am using JSP and mysql as database.

Appreciate your comments.

Comment: Of course, this can easily be done within a user session with the help of AJAX. What is the specific question?

Comment: This statement of yours - "*I am managing different tables in MySQL for each query*" looks somewhat wonky. Different tables for each query, why?

Comment: I want to insert a row in mysql table with the comment given by user for that query. Suppose when a user logs in he sees 3 queries from different users. First query is associated with table1, 2nd with table2 in mysql. When a user answers the 2nd query, I want to insert a row in table2 with the comments given by user. How would I make sure in my code that which query is associated with which table? Is there a way to store information that the first query is associated with which table?

Comment: Then what is the best way to that? I was doing it like, for each query and its comments, there will be one table with first row as the query and others as comments on that query.

Comment: You would need an identifier for the div in order to know the table where the data should be inserted, maybe inside a `<input type="hidden" />` field.